# Put form data into a PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have this form

```
  <form action = "put the data to a single PHP array" method="post">
    <input name="a" type="text" />
    <input name="b" type="text" />
    <input name="c" type="text" /> 
    <input name="d" type="text" /> 
    <input type="button">
  </form>
```

the condition is that I want to put the data into a PHP array when the user filled the form and click the submit button. the data should be order the way the text input fields are arranged. how can I do that?

Pls help me with the code. thanks!

Comment: Just give an action value to your form and submit it :) and you will get your data with either `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Comment: hi hanky and kermit. I know how to use the action and method functions of the form. what i dont know is the part where the form data will be put to a single PHP array.

Comment: do you mean whatever the data the user fills in you wanted it to be accessed as an array in the next page

Comment: You could rename your fields like `my_array[a], my_array[b]` and form data would lay in separate array `$_POST['my_array']`

Comment: @NaveenThally thats what I wanted to do. that before sending the data to another page it should be in an array form.

Comment: @sectus thanks that answers my question to.

Comment: I fail to see the reason for all the downvotes and close votes. I think the question is sufficiently clear and can be adequately answered.

Comment: Thanks @RobbyCornelissen I just hope they know how to read carefully

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the name of your inputs like this:

```
<form action = "put the data to a single PHP array" method="post">
    <input name="a[]" type="text" />
    <input name="a[]" type="text" />
    <input name="a[]" type="text" /> 
    <input name="a[]" type="text" /> 
    <input type="button"/>
</form>
```

You can then retrieve the array as follows:

```
$values = $_POST['a'];
```

Answer (score 1):

hi Jonas if you need the values to be passed as an array then you can use

```
<form action = "submit the data to a PHP array" method="post">
     <input name="ar[]" type="text" />
     <input name="ar[]" type="text" />
     <input name="ar[]" type="text" /> 
     <input name="ar[]" type="text" /> 
     <input type="button">
</form>
```

while accessing  you can use

```
$ar=$_POST['ar'];
$size=sizeof($ar);
    for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++)
    {
      echo "$ar[$i]";
    }
```

Generally we use this type of array passing when we 
use **multiple checkboxes** value to be passed